# Custom indexer using elasticsearch Magento 2.4

Tags: elasticsearch, magento, magento2, magento2.2, magento2.1

I followed the documentation i.e.https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-indexing.html#run-reindex-by-command to create a custom Indexer.
It is visible at the backend.

After this, I want to push this custom index using elastic search so that it can be used in the search.
Please guide me on this part.

Rashi

Comment: As per the documentation after running reindex command the data should get indexed to elasticsearch. Once indexed it should be searchable

Comment: Yes @Nishant you are right. But that will only work for products. I want to add custom indexes like search on customer data (it can be name,address or anything). I want to add multiple custom indexes according to my project requirement. So, for this case I need solution to implement the same.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this. I also want to do the same and want to create a separate index for customer which i am able to create. But not able to Push the data into it. It pushes the data into Product indexes.

Comment: We developed it through customization or you can buy extension to perform the same